# Cannot change a QWidget's `foregroundRole` & `backgroundRole`(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda)

There is a `LineNumberArea` class, which is used to draw a line number area on the left of the textedit area.

```cpp
class LineNumberArea : public QWidget
```

> [The location of this class](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/master/src/ui/linenumberarea.h#L8)

[image: A Preview]

> Of course, the gray area is the Line Number Area.

Then, I wanted to change the color of `LineNumberArea`. I saw [`setForegroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setForegroundRole) and [`setBackgroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setBackgroundRole).

I just wrote this:

```cpp
...
  lineNumberArea = new LineNumberArea(this);
  lineNumberArea->setForegroundRole(QPalette::HighlightedText);
  lineNumberArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
...
```

> [The location of the code](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/master/src/core/texteditor.cpp#L17)

But nothing has changed!

I wrote some debug code:

```cpp
  qDebug() << lineNumberArea->foregroundRole();
  qDebug() << lineNumberArea->backgroundRole();
```

And output is:

```
QPalette::HighlightedText
QPalette::Base
```

I am confused now. Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: A quick look at the [relevant source](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/master/src/core/texteditor.cpp#L218) shows the background to be hard coded as `painter.fillRect(event->rect(), Qt::lightGray);` .

Comment: @G.M. Thank you! I am stupid..... haha